# Mocking a servlet, How do I go about mocking this correctly?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Im having trouble testing this.

the line 
    ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
is giving me grief, should this be mocked and if so how would I go about it?
 The error im getting is from it is.
      java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServletConfig has not been initialized

My code is

```
  public class StockSearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    String dateOut = "yyyy/MM/dd";        
    DateTimeFormatter ldtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateOut);
    String symbol = request.getParameter("symbol");
    String from = request.getParameter("from");
    DateTime fromDate = new DateTime(ldtf.parseDateTime(from));
    String until = request.getParameter("until");
    DateTime untilDate = new DateTime(ldtf.parseDateTime(until));
    String interval = request.getParameter("interval");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    StockQuery stockQuery = null;
    try {
        stockQuery = new StockQuery(symbol,from,until);
        stockQuery.setInterval(interval);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StockSearchServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    session.setAttribute("stockQuery", stockQuery);        
    StockService stockService = ServiceFactory.getStockServiceInstance();
    List<StockQuote> quotes = new ArrayList<StockQuote>();

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        quotes = stockService.getQuote(symbol,fromDate, untilDate ,StockService.getIntervalEnum(interval));
    } catch (StockServiceException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(StockSearchServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    for (StockQuote stockQuote : quotes) {
        stringBuilder.append("<br>"+ stockQuote.getSymbol() + " " + stockQuote.getPrice() + " " + stockQuote.getDate());
    }
    String outputStockString = stringBuilder.toString();
    session.setAttribute("outputStockString", outputStockString);

    ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/stockquoteResults.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

This is my current test im using

```
  @Test
  public void testDoPost() throws IOException, ServletException {
    String symbol = "GOOG";
    String from = "2015/10/05";
    String until = "2015/10/09";
    String interval = "day";

    StockSearchServlet stockSearchServlet = new StockSearchServlet();
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    when(request.getParameter("symbol")).thenReturn(symbol);
    when(request.getParameter("from")).thenReturn(from);
    when(request.getParameter("until")).thenReturn(until);
    when(request.getParameter("interval")).thenReturn(interval);
    when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(new MySession());
    HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    //when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(new MySession());
    new StockSearchServlet().doPost(request, response);
    //stockSearchServlet.doPost(request, response);

    String outputString = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("outputStockString");
    assertEquals("verify state", outputString.length(), 1);
}
```

and this class is part of the test class.

```
   class MySession implements HttpSession {
    private Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @Override
    public long getCreationTime() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getLastAccessedTime() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return new ServletContext() {
            @Override
            public String getContextPath() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public ServletContext getContext(String s) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public int getMajorVersion() {
                return 0;
            }
            @Override
            public int getMinorVersion() {
                return 0;
            }
            @Override
            public int getEffectiveMajorVersion() {
                return 0;
            }
            @Override
            public int getEffectiveMinorVersion() {
                return 0;
            }
            @Override
            public String getMimeType(String s) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public Set<String> getResourcePaths(String s) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public URL getResource(String s) throws MalformedURLException {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String s) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public RequestDispatcher getRequestDispatcher(String s) {
                return new RequestDispatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void forward(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
                    }
                    @Override            
                    public void include(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
                    }
                };
            }
            @Override
            public RequestDispatcher getNamedDispatcher(String s) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public Servlet getServlet(String s) throws ServletException {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public Enumeration<Servlet> getServlets() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getServletNames() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public void log(String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void log(Exception e, String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void log(String s, Throwable throwable) {
            }
            @Override
            public String getRealPath(String s) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public String getServerInfo() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public String getInitParameter(String s) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getInitParameterNames() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean setInitParameter(String s, String s1) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public Object getAttribute(String s) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getAttributeNames() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public void setAttribute(String s, Object o) {
            }
            @Override
            public void removeAttribute(String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public String getServletContextName() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public ServletRegistration.Dynamic addServlet(String s, String s1) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public ServletRegistration.Dynamic addServlet(String s, Servlet servlet) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public ServletRegistration.Dynamic addServlet(String s, Class<? extends Servlet> aClass) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public <T extends Servlet> T createServlet(Class<T> aClass) throws ServletException {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public ServletRegistration getServletRegistration(String s) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> getServletRegistrations() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public FilterRegistration.Dynamic addFilter(String s, String s1) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public FilterRegistration.Dynamic addFilter(String s, Filter filter) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public FilterRegistration.Dynamic addFilter(String s, Class<? extends Filter> aClass) {
               return null;
            }
            @Override
            public <T extends Filter> T createFilter(Class<T> aClass) throws ServletException {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public FilterRegistration getFilterRegistration(String s) {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public Map<String, ? extends FilterRegistration> getFilterRegistrations() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public SessionCookieConfig getSessionCookieConfig() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public void setSessionTrackingModes(Set<SessionTrackingMode> set) {
            }
            @Override
            public Set<SessionTrackingMode> getDefaultSessionTrackingModes() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public Set<SessionTrackingMode> getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public void addListener(String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public <T extends EventListener> void addListener(T t) {
            }
            @Override
            public void addListener(Class<? extends EventListener> aClass) {
            }
            @Override
            public <T extends EventListener> T createListener(Class<T> aClass) throws ServletException {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public JspConfigDescriptor getJspConfigDescriptor() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public void declareRoles(String... strings) {
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxInactiveInterval(int interval) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getMaxInactiveInterval() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpSessionContext getSessionContext() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAttribute(String name) {
        return attributes.get(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(String name) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getAttributeNames() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getValueNames() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void setAttribute(String name, Object value) {
        attributes.put(name,value);
    }

    @Override
    public void putValue(String name, Object value) {

    }

    @Override
    public void removeAttribute(String name) {

    }

    @Override
    public void removeValue(String name) {

    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to avoid mocking `getServletContext()` and `RequestDispatcher` with a little minor refactoring, or you can just choose to mock them.

Here are 3 possible approaches:

**1)** You could put the code that gets the `ServletContext` and forwards to the jsp page (the last 3 lines of your `doPost()`) in a protected method (let's call it `dispatchToJSP()`), and in your test you call `doPost()` on a subclass of `StockSearchServlet` which overrides `dispatchToJSP()` to just do an assert to verify the jsp path.

For example, in your test:

```
StockSearchServlet stockSearchServlet = new StockSearchServlet() {
  @Override
  protected void dispatchToJSP(String path) {
      assertEquals("verify jsp path", path, "/stockquoteResults.jsp");
  }
};
```

You might also want the overridden method to set a boolean flag in the subclass indicating that the method was called, in which case it may be better to use a non-anonymous subclass with a method to retrieve the flag.

**2**) A more elegant approach might be a refactoring to delegate the task of dispatching to the jsp to a specialized class (via an interface, preferably - let's call it `IDispatcher`) which does only dispatching, and the you mock that interface to verify that it was called with the correct jsp path and then create a separate test class to test your real `IDispatcher` implementation properly in an isolated test. So you would replace the last 3 lines of your `doPost()` by `this.dispatcher.forwardTo("/stockquoteResults.jsp");` and in your test you would set a mock dispatcher in the servlet under test and call `verify(mockDispatcher).forwardTo("/stockquoteResults.jsp");` or something like that. This is probably the approach resulting in the cleanest, best-designed, most re-usable code, but it's more work. If you have only 1 servlet, it might not be worth the extra work.

**3)** If you do decide to just mock everything without modifying your `StockSearchServlet` class itself, the trick of testing a subclass of `StockSearchServlet` allows you to overrride `getServletContext()` to return a mock (which would in turn return a mock of `RequestDispatcher`):

```
final ServletContext myMockServletContext = mock(ServletContext.class);
StockSearchServlet stockSearchServlet = new StockSearchServlet() {
  @Override
  public ServletContext getServletContext() {
      return myMockServletContext;
  }
};
```

This third approach is simple, but it feels ugly because it's very implementation-dependent and has mocks returning mocks.  The servlet API doesn't change often, though, so I think it's okay for this situation, and the mocks have to return mocks because of questionable design in the servlet API (why isn't there just a `forward()` method in `HttpServlet`?).

Comment: I added a mock return from the getServletContext method now I get a null pointer exception from the   dispatcher.forward(request, response);  line.   Any idea why this may happen?

Comment: So you chose approach 3, it seems.  In my answer I mentioned that the mock you return from `getServletContext()` needs to return a mock of `RequestDispatcher`.  It sounds like you didn't implement that part.  You should also call verify on the `RequestDispatcher` mock to confirm that `forward()` is called with the right JSP path.

Comment: I made some other corrections since, one of them was adding a mock dispatcher. I cleared the null pointer issue and I have the test method running completely I just need to add some assert statements now. I will post what I changed in the next day or so. And thank you did help lead me in the right direction.